# Are there any hydrogen atom stationary states that have non zero electric dipole moment expectation value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, parity

I have to show that an electron in the $n=2$ state of a hydrogen atom may have non zero expectation value of electric dipole moment, that is  $\langle p_e\rangle\neq 0$. However, $p_e$ is odd under parity which means that $\langle n'l'm'|p_e|nlm\rangle =0 $ if $l+l'$ is even. Since $\langle p_e\rangle=\langle nlm|p_e|nlm\rangle$ I have $l+l=2l$ (Laporte's Rule) which means that $\langle p_e\rangle = 0$ for  any $n$ or $l$. I really don't see how can the expectation value be different from zero. The problem is from Griffiths Introduction to Quantum Mechanics 3rd edition (problem 6.13).

Here is the full problem:

> Consider an electron in a hydrogen atom.
>
> a) Show that if the electron is in the ground state, then necessarily $\langle p_e \rangle = 0$. No calculations allowed.
>
> b) Show that if the electron is in the $n=2$ state, then $\langle p_e \rangle$ need not vanish. Give an example of a wave function for the energy level $n=2$ that has a non-vanishing $\langle p_e \rangle$ and compute $\langle p_e \rangle$ for this state."

I really care only for the first part of b). If  I get that I think I will be able to do the rest.

This problem is for chapter 6.4.3 "Parity Selection Rules"

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the problem. Can you please state 6.13 word-for-word as it appears in Griffiths? (I don’t have the book.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way around it is to realise that there are degeneracies in these states. So for $n=2$ state, you can take linear combination of different $l$ states. And once you do that you can have cross terms that contribute to the integral.

Comment: Ok, so I could have a state like (|200>+|210>)/sqrt(2) for which <p_e>=0.5*<200 + 210|p_e| 200 + 210> = 0.5*(<200|p_e|210> + <210|p_e|200>) which doesn't vanish.  Is that right ?

Comment: Yes. That’s right.

Comment: Thank you ! I got it